# Error inertia-link in pagination component

Tags: vue.js, inertiajs

hello it's not exactly related to vue but more to inertia

i'm using vue 3 for this

this is my page

```
<template>
    <div class="bg-white rounded-md shadow overflow-x-auto">
        <table class="w-full whitespace-nowrap">
            <tr class="text-left font-bold">
                <th class="px-6 pt-6 pb-4">Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="log in logs.data" class="hover:bg-gray-100 focus-within:bg-gray-100">
                <td class="border-t">
                    <inertia-link class="px-6 py-4 flex items-center focus:text-indigo-500" :href="route('logging.logs.index', log.id)">
                        {{ log.action }}
                    </inertia-link>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr v-if="logs.data.length === 0">
                <td class="border-t px-6 py-4" colspan="4">No logs found.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <pagination class="mt-6" :links="logs.links"/>
</template>

<script>
import Pagination from "@/Components/Pagination";

export default {
    components: {
        Pagination,
    },
    props: {
        logs: Object,
        filters: Object,
    },
}
</script>
```

this is component

```
<template>
    <div v-if="links.length > 3">
        <div class="flex flex-wrap -mb-1">
            <template v-for="link in links">
                <div v-if="link.url === null" class="mr-1 mb-1 px-4 py-3 text-sm leading-4 text-gray-400 border rounded" v-html="link.label"/>
                <inertia-link v-else class="mr-1 mb-1 px-4 py-3 text-sm leading-4 border rounded hover:bg-white focus:border-indigo-500 focus:text-indigo-500" :class="{ 'bg-white': link.active }" :href="link.url" v-html="link.label"/>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        links: Array,
    },
}
</script>
```

and the problem is inertia-link in pagination component it throws Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: i.default is not a function

in main template for page itself inertia link works and also it works if i change it to standard a tag

Answer (score 2):

Import Link component as inertia-link in the app.js file:

```
import {createInertiaApp, Link} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
    setup({el, app, props, plugin}) {
        return createApp({render: () => h(app, props)})
            .component('inertia-link', Link)
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ElementPlus)
            .mixin({methods: {route}})
            .mount(el);
    },
});`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by using this template:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="links.length > 3">
    <div class="flex flex-wrap -mb-1">
      <template v-for="(link, key) in links" :key="key">
        <div v-if="link.url === null"  class="mr-1 mb-1 px-4 py-3 text-sm leading-4 text-gray-400 border rounded" v-html="link.label" />
        <inertia-link v-else class="mr-1 mb-1 px-4 py-3 text-sm leading-4 border rounded hover:bg-white focus:border-indigo-500 focus:text-indigo-500" :class="{ 'bg-white': link.active }" :href="link.url"><span v-html="link.label"></span></inertia-link>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```